# C++ class в чём разница?

Tags: c++

В чём различия данных строк? Обе работают. Когда тот или другой случай используется?

- `Class* obj = new Class();`
- `Class obj;`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731550/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c/731557

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В первом случае Вы создаёте объект в куче. Сами выделяете память, сами должны её удалять оператором **`delete`**. Обращение к полям и методам объекта происходит через стрелку **`->`**.

Во втором случае объект создаётся в стеке, он будет автоматически уделён по завершению его области видимости. Обращение к объекту происходит через точку `.`

Первый способ позволяет определять любое время жизни объекта, использовать его в разных частях программы. Но это также чревато последствиями, так как программист может забыть удалить объект из памяти. Поэтому без необходимости объект не следует создавать в куче.

Answer (score 3):

Уточню, что для второго объекта деструктор вызывается автоматически, при выходе потока управления из функции.
В принципе, в 90% процентах, можно писать без new-delete.

Comment: Не очень понял: для чего/кого уточнение? Об удалении объекта сказано в первой же фразе ответа @AivanF.