# Зачем нужны динамические массивы в C++?

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

В учебниках по C++ пишут, что динамические массивы нужны, когда заранее неизвестны размеры этих массивов. Потом идет объяснение, как выделять указателями память из кучи, затем ее надо освобождать и т.д.

Но я попробовал сделать без указателей, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    int array[size];

    cout << sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

и все работает. Память, получается, выделяется динамически и без указателей. Т.е. во время написания программы, мы не знали размера массива а ввели его уже во время выполнения программы. Так в чем подвох, почему нужно делать с указателями а так, как я сделал нельзя?

Comment: Можно и так. Это называется [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Подвох тут, прежде всего в доступном размере (ну, есть и ряд других тонкостей, прежде всего "время жизни" такого массива ограничено текущей активацией функции). Иногда это как раз удобно, зависит от стоящих перед вами задач...

Comment: а ещё подвох в том, что это расширение Си; а в C++ это, вообще говоря, некорректный код, хотя gcc и некоторые другие его и допускают...

Comment: И как вы определите размер так, если  у вас будет, например,  массив указателей на символ?..

Answer (score 11):

Это работает **только в конкретном компиляторе**, в котором реализовано данное расширение. Стандартом С++ такое не предусмотрено, только С (да и то реализация не является строго необходимой).

Это примерно как если бы вам говорили, что молоток - только для забивания гвоздей, а вы бы возражали - а вот у меня молоток такой, что я им могу еще и шурупы вертеть. Поверю, что у вас молоток с ручкой в виде отвертки (сам такой в школе на трудах делал :)), но это не значит, что молоток вообще приспособлен для такой деятельности...

P.S. И еще - динамические массивы нужны не только тогда, когда количество элементов неизвестно заранее. Но еще и для больших размеров, например, или для строго регулируемого времени жизни - словом, неизвестный заранее размер - не единственная причина их использования.

Comment: VLA вообще-то вещь удобная и наверное ее все же внесут в стандарт. А если нет, то как говориться, в топку такие стандарты (вместе с их создателями)

Answer (score 3):

> В учебниках по C++ пишут, что динамические массивы нужны, когда заранее неизвестны размеры этих массивов

Да, это одна из причин. Но, возможно добавить какие-то ограничения в программу, чтобы минимизировать "ущерб" от отсутствия таких массивов.

> Так в чем подвох, почему нужно делать с указателями а так, как я сделал нельзя?

Также важно время хранения этого массива. Создавая массив на стеке его время хранения получается автоматическим, и массив будет уничтожен при выходе из функции. Что мы получаем при динамическом выделении памяти:

1. Можем определиться с размером во время выполнения.
2. Контроль времени жизни объектов в этой памяти.
3. Больший объем памяти, нежели объем "стандартного" стека.

Подробнее здесь: [Определение объектов в C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731550/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c/)

> и все работает

Здесь возможны несколько вариантов.

1. Ваш компилятор поддерживает возможность создания таких массивов, реализуя расширения языка, например, расширение VLA ([Variable-Length Arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) в GCC.
2. Компилятор поддерживает возможность RSA ([Runtime-Sized Arrays](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3639.html)), которую хотели добавить в C++14, но так и не добавили. Но разработчики поспешили её добавить в компилятор и Вам досталась та самая версия этого компилятора.

То есть на текущий момент возможности создавать такие массивы в языке нет.
Опять же, вполне вероятно, что лучшим вариантом будет воспользоваться одним из стандартных контейнеров, или, хотя бы умными указателями.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим я хочу написать функцию создания массива по заданному размеру для заданного указателя. Я напишу так:

```
int* new_array(int* p, size_t sz)
{        
    p = new int[sz];
    return p;
}
```

А теперь я напишу без выделения памяти в динамической области (как вы показали):

```
int* fudge(int* p, size_t sz)
{
    if(sz > sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0])) {
        int m[sz];
        p = m;
    }
    return p;

}
```

Напишите программу использовав то одну, то другую функцию и убедитесь, что вторая на самом деле является вздором. Вот о чем речь, когда говорится о неизвестном размере, плюс ко всему сказанному ранее.

Comment: Я только в самом начале своего обучения, поэтому Ваш пример немного сложноват для моего понимания. Но постараюсь разобраться. Спасибо, всем кто ответил, я сделал для себя определенные выводы.